# Powerpoint 2013 mangles URL when printing to PDF?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

I have the following *good* URL in a footnote to a slide:

`https://cs.brown.edu/people/rtamassi/gdhandbook/chapters/force-directed.pdf`

On Windows 10, I tried printing to PDF using both the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer and the "Foxit PhantomPDF Printer".  I get an *seemingly* identical looking but *bad* URL in the PDF output:

`https://cs.brown.edu/people/rtamassi/gdhandbook/chapters/force‐directed.pdf`

I used [this URL decoder](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder) to encode both URLs in order to find the difference.  The *good* URL is:

`https%3A%2F%2Fcs.brown.edu%2Fpeople%2Frtamassi%2Fgdhandbook%2Fchapters%2Fforce-directed.pdf`

The *bad* URL is:

`https%3A%2F%2Fcs.brown.edu%2Fpeople%2Frtamassi%2Fgdhandbook%2Fchapters%2Fforce%E2%80%90directed.pdf`

Neither of the encoded URLs work in Firefox, but I thought that it should reveal subtle differences in the characters.  I am still research what the `%` codes are, but he encoded URLs do show that the difference is in the dash.  The "good" dash is ASCII encodable while the "bad" dash is some compound character.  I can avoid the bad URL in my PDF output by using the encoded URL, but it creates a lot of cognitive noise, especially when footnoting multiple URLs.

**Is there any way to have the ASCII-encodable dash preserved in my PDF output?**

**Even if I could do that, is it wise?**  If there is a risk that PDF processing tools (croppers, n-uppers, rotaters, etc.) will not preserve the "good" dash, then it seems better to go with the encoded URL, even though the cognitive noise would significantly degrade the slide.

Note that I tried hyperlinking the URL text in the Powerpoint file, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

I also noticed that not all mangled URLs fail.  For example, the following two URLs work, even though the dash is modified in the PDF.  Maybe most HTTP servers are robust against different dashes.

```
In Powerpoint:
https://graphviz.org/resources/#language-bindings

In PDF:
https://graphviz.org/resources/#language‐bindings
```

In case it clarifies my situation, I put the good and bad URLs into Vim to see what the codes are.

```
Good dash: Decimal  45,  Hex 2d,  Octal 055
 Bad dash: Decimal 8208, Hex 2010, Oct 20020, Digraph -1
```

From [this "dash" page](https://jkorpela.fi/dashes.html), the "good" dash is a "hyphen-minus" while the "bad" dash is a "hyphen".  Replacing the hyphen-minus with `%2d` works for the original URL above, but doesn't always work, e.g., for the good URL `https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java#user-content-how-it-works`, for which the mangled version is `https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz‐java#user‐content‐how‐it‐works`. The "fixed" version is `https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz%2djava#user%2dcontent%2dhow%2dit%2dworks` fails on Firefox but works for Chrome and Edge. I'm still stuck with trying to find a way to ideally preserve the hyphen-minus symbols or to rejig URLs in a robust manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the hyphen ("dash") with its HTML escape sequence: ‐ or -, depending on [Unicode](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/punctuation/hyphen/) or [not](https://mateam.net/html-escape-characters/). See also https://wikimass.com/html/entities/hyphen

Comment: Can you please clarify your phrase "depending  on Unicode or not"?  Depending on what is Unicode or not?  In the original question, I'll add the codes for the "good" and "bad" dash that is reported by Vim, in case that clarifies my situation.

Comment: [This page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) says that the percent codes in an encoded URL are 2-digit hexadecimal numbers.  Based on that, I tried your idea of replacing only the hyphen in the bad URL with `%2d`, which worked for the first and original URL in my posted question.  **However**, if I try to make the URL more readable by using capitals, e.g., `Force\%2dDirected`, the URL is interpretted as a webpage rather than a document, and fails.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't always work, e.g., for the good URL `https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java#user-content-how-it-works`, for which the mangled version is `https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz‐java#user‐content‐how‐it‐works`. The "fixed" version is `https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz%2djava#user%2dcontent%2dhow%2dit%2dworks` fails on Firefox but works for Chrome and Edge. I guess I'm still stuck with trying to find a way to ideally preserve the hyphen-minus symbols or rejig a URL in a robust manner.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work-around.  For all textboxes in Powerpoint in which hyphen-minus must be preserved, ensure that the font is fixed-width, e.g, consolas.

Of course, this changes the space required and may not be to the liking of the author.  It might work if the user decides only to format the hyphen-minus symbols as fixed-width, along with any font size adjustments needed to compensate for the font change.

The ideal solution would be if text wasn't modified against the will of authors, without their knowledge, when generating PDF.  But we'll have to see whether such improvements occur in the future.